# Ado vs Entity Framework with .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I am working on a project with support of multiple DB

1) Sql

2) My Sql

with .Net Core 2.

I will use DB as per client requirements.

I have a concern related to access layer performance, there are two options to use data access layer, either Entity Framework or Ado.Net.

As we know entity framework is bit slow for first request as compare to Ado.Net because EF loads metadata into memory, that takes a time. in .Net framework, But currently the mapper is no more in .Net Core so which one performance will be better either ado.Net of Ef with .Net Core2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures

Comment: Have you measured the performance for your situation by running performance and load tests?

Comment: I have done some research related to same from below link but i am bit confuse in .Net core 2, which one will be better option ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107992/performance-analyze-ado-net-and-entity-framework

Comment: what about using [Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/info)? it's built for speed... I would also suggest that if you choose to use raw ADO.Net, you might be able to benefit from my [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper), but you will need to extend it if you want to support MySqlClient.

Comment: @DenseCrab that is 8+ years out of date, ef core is different